# Cross Domain Request with TypeScript and Angular $http Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and I am trying to set up cross domain requests with the $http service.  In the past with JavaScript I was able to something like this:

```
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

When I look at the [IRequestConfig options](http://definitelytyped.org/docs/angularjs--angular/interfaces/ng.irequestconfig.html#method) of the DefinitivelyTyped class required to use AngularJS I see that there is a withCredentials property but not a useXDomain property.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that it is possible to do this, which may seem like bad news.  But I have good news.  You don't need to do this, because setting `useXDomain` to `true` has no effect.  In fact, **`useXDomain` is [not even really a thing](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/angular/kl2BVOubG4I) in Angular**.

[Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) is a great tutorial on CORS for more info.

Comment: +1 Would like to add that the *definition* was correct and the ops original code was *wrong* and typescript caught it for them :)

Comment: Thanks!  You are exactly right - useXDomain is not needed.  I've exorcised it from the code base.  Ironically the reason I was getting cross domain errors was due to that fact that my URL was invalid and would have normally been getting a 404!  :)

Comment: cannot understan that. the problem is to set it. how coan not be athing? there's the necessity to solve the classical devlepoement localhost to api server issues...